How to reference the spaCy pipeline in pyproject.toml file?
I am creating a pyproject.toml file for a package (using setuptools 69.2.0) that uses the spaCy library.  My goal is to have the spaCy pipeline download as part of the "pip install [package]" process.  My issue is the pipeline is not a dependency, but rather installed with "python -m spacy download en_core_web_sm".  What is the correct way to call the download in the pyproject.toml file?
spaCy installed correctly (editable package install locally) by including it as a dependency in the .toml file, but the pipeline needs to be downloaded for it to work and I cannot determine how to correctly include it in the .toml file.

Python build tools don't recommend to run user code at build or installation time. With pure pyproject.toml it's impossible at all. Possible if you add setup.py and run your code in it; don't forget to check arguments to avoid re-downloading en_core_web_sm every time.

I don't know if this is the accepted way, but I managed to do it by supplying the URL of the pipelines wheel in the pyproject.toml like this:
[project]
...
dependencies = [
    "spacy>=3.7.6",
    "de-core-news-lg @ https://github.com/explosion/spacy-models/releases/download/de_core_news_lg-3.7.0/de_core_news_lg-3.7.0-py3-none-any.whl",
]

You can find releases for the pipelines you need here:
https://github.com/explosion/spacy-models/releases
I used rye to install it via the URL and add it to my pyproject.toml:
rye add de-core-news-lg --url="https://github.com/explosion/spacy-models/releases/download/de_core_news_lg-3.7.0/de_core_news_lg-3.7.0-py3-none-any.whl"

You could also just pass the URL directly to pip, you can find some examples here, if you prefer that:
pip install 'de-core-news-lg @ https://github.com/explosion/spacy-models/releases/download/de_core_news_lg-3.7.0/de_core_news_lg-3.7.0-py3-none-any.whl'

By no means a perfect solution, but this should achieve what you want.
